# Clojure macro to collect strings in constant

Tags: macros, clojure

I've got a Clojure file with a lot of string constants. I want to collect these strings in a collection by wrapping them in a macro. After several tries I succeeded, but my solution looks fairly hideous.

```
(ns Memorable)
(def MEMORY (atom []))
(defmacro memorize [s] (swap! MEMORY conj s) s)

(prn (str (memorize "hello") " brave new " (memorize "world")))  ;  test

(defmacro make-memories-constant [] `(def MEMORIES ~(deref MEMORY)))
(make-memories-constant)
```

Are there more elegant solutions for this problem?

Comment: Why is `memorize` a macro? Why are you mapping `identity` across a vector, and then creating a new vector of the results?

Comment: @Mike Douglas: Making `memorize` a macro removes the function call overhead from run time (the `conj` onto `MEMORY` happens when the macro is expanded). Agreed on the second point though.

Comment: What is the purpose of this?  Do you want to collect the strings for translation purposes?

Comment: The map was unnecessary, I've removed it now. The macro is necessary, not for performance, but because when the code is compiled, the macro-expand phase is skipped and MEMORY will be empty.

Comment: @Stuart I've got a clojure file with named rules for french grammar. An example is: turn "c" into "ç" before an ending starting with "[aou]". I need a list of rules, code that, given a french sentence, can tell which rules were applied, and code that, given a named rule, can produce french sentences using that rule (e.g. "Nous commençons").

I want all data for each rule defined in a single place.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you're writing an interpreter for a domain-specific language.  Your domain-specific language gives rules for French spelling.  I don't know how the rules are represented, but I think you need to figure out how to represent them as a set of data structures.  Then you can write one function that, given a set of rules and a sentence, recognizes which rules were used in the sentence; and another function that applies the rules to generate a sentence.

Comment: If I represent them as data structures, I lose the advantage of being able to use arbitrary code in the rules.

I would still like to know if it's possible to write the last two lines more succinctly - as an anonymous macro, so to speak.

Answer (score 1):

As far as code cleanup is concerned, I'd remove the `make-memories-constant` macro -- you can just do

```
(def MEMORIES @MEMORY)
```

or even

```
(def MEMORY @MEMORY)
```

so as not to clutter your namespace with another Var. As long as you put this after all calls to `memorize`, this will save a snapshot of `MEMORY` with all `memorize`d strings inside.

I'd say this is actually pretty clean, with the actual code executing at runtime no different from what it would have been without any `memorize`-ing...

Another approach would be to prepare a sort of "memorisation framework" as a separate namespace exporting a macros called `setup-memorization`, say, which could look something like this (<strike>just a rough sketch *which won't work without some polishing*...</strike> **updated with a (not so thoroughly) tested version -- this actually works!**... still, please tweak it to your needs):

```
(ns memorization-framework)

(defmacro setup-memorization []
  (let [MEMORY (gensym "MEMORY")
        MEMORIES (gensym "MEMORIES")]
    `(do (def ~MEMORY (atom []))
         (defmacro ~'memorize [s#] (swap! ~MEMORY conj s#) s#)
         (defmacro ~'get-memory [] @~MEMORY)
         (defmacro ~'defmemories [~MEMORIES]
           `(do (def ~~MEMORIES @~~MEMORY)
                (ns-unmap ~~*ns* '~'~'get-memory)
                (ns-unmap ~~*ns* '~'~'memorize)
                (ns-unmap ~~*ns* '~'~MEMORY)
                ~~MEMORIES)))))
```

Then you'd `use` the `memorization-framework` namespace, do `(setup-memorization)` towards the top of your namespace to set things up, call `memorize` like you do in your example code to memorise things and finally use <strike>`end-memorization`</strike> `defmemories` to store the string collection <strike>somewhere</strike> in a Var and remove the temporary Var used to store the atom used for construction-time storage along with the ability to make further calls to `memorize` from this namespace. (<strike>The `end-memorization` macro is meant to just return the collection to wherever you call it from when called with no arguments or define a new Var to store it if given a single argument, which must be a symbol to be used to name the Var.</strike> Update: I've only tested the `defmemories` version, so I'm leaving it here and removing the "in-place return" variant.)

An example interaction at the REPL while in namespace `foo` (note I defined `setup-memorization` in the `user` namespace):

```
foo> (user/setup-memorization)
#'foo/defmemories
foo> (get-memory)
[]
foo> (memorize "foo")
"foo"
foo> (memorize "bar")
"bar"
foo> (get-memory)
["foo" "bar"]
foo> (defmemories quux)
["foo" "bar"]
foo> quux
["foo" "bar"]
foo> (get-memory)
; Evaluation aborted.
foo> (memorize)
; Evaluation aborted.
```

Those "Evaluation aborted." messages indicate that calls to `get-memory` and `memorize` throw exceptions after `defmemories` has been called. This is by design, as mentioned above. Also, `get-memory` is here mostly to ease testing / debugging.

If you're only going to use all this once, the `setup-memorization` approach might be overkill, but I guess it'll remove some boilerplate for you if you use it more.